# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError after updating to Angular 9 on changing parent property from the child when Ivy is enabled

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

I recently updated my Angular project to version 9. I was using a service to update the header of the main menu and it was working successfully but now generates this error:

> core.js:5828 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError:
>   Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value:
>   'main title'. Current value: 'new title'.

This error occurs every time the title changes.

This is part of my code:

My routing:

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],

    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'warehouse',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./systems/warehouse/warehouse.module').then(
            m => m.WarehouseModule
          )
      },
      {
        path: 'commerce',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./systems/commerce/commerce.module').then(
            m => m.CommerceModule
          )
      },
      {
...
```

The main component:

**main.component.ts:**

```
  pageTitle: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mainService.pageTitle$.subscribe((title: string) => {
      this.pageTitle = title;
    });
...
```

The service I'm using to change the title:
**main.service.ts:**

```
  public setTitle(title: string) {
    this.pageTitle$.emit(title);
  }
```

And finally one of my clients inside warehouse module that changes the title:

**main.service.ts:**

```
this.mainService.setTitle('new title');
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem happens just when Ivy is enabled and in development mode. There is no error with *"enableIvy": false* or when production.

Comment: if possible can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz.com

Comment: How can I start a Stackblits with Angular 9?

Comment: you can replace the below lines in package.json

`"@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.0-rc.1"`

Comment: What's pageTitle$? Is it an EventEmitter?

Comment: @Rajat Yes. it is.

Comment: Did you try emitting the event asynchronously? Something like pageTitle$ = new EventEmitter(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling 'setTitle' function in ngOnInit. Calling it from the constructor fixed the problem.

This makes an error when not in production mode:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.mainService.setTitle('My title');
}
```

And this fixes the problem:

```
constructor(
  private mainService: MainService
) {
  this.mainService.setTitle('My title');
}
```

Comment: What if you have to change the title after getting Params from routing. So, you have to use the setTitle method inside the `ngOnInitMethod`. And it gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

What if you have to change the title after getting Params from routing. So, you have to use the setTitle method inside the ngOnInitMethod. And it gives an error.

To prevent this, I added a change detector to the AppComponent:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {

  constructor(public title: Title, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,) {
    this.titl.setHeaderTitle('Home');
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); // It fixes but can lead to performance issues.
  }

}
```